# Multiple result sets and return value handling while calling sql server stored procedure from Groovy

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, groovy, resultset

I have MS SQL Server stored procedure (SQL Server 2012) which returns:

1. return value describing procedure execution result in general (successfull or not) with `return @RetCode` statement (RetCode is int type)
2. one result set (several records with 5 fields each)
3. another result set (several records with 3 fields each)

I calling this procedure from my Groovy (and Java) code using Java's CallableStatement object and I cannot find right way to handle all three outputs.

My last attempt is

```
CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call Procedure_Name($param_1, $param_2)}")
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER)
boolean result = proc.execute()
int returnValue = proc.getInt(1)
println(returnValue)
while(result){
    ResultSet rs = proc.getResultSet()
    println("rs")
    result = proc.getMoreResults()
}
```

And now I get exception:

```
Output parameters have not yet been processed. Call getMoreResults()
```

I tried several approaches for some hours but didn't find correct one. Some others produced another exceptions.

Could you please help me with the issue?

Thanks In Advance!

**Update** (for Tim):
 I see rc while I launched code:

```
 Connection connection = dbGetter().connection 
 CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call Procedure_Name($param_1, $param_2)}") 
 boolean result = proc.execute() 
 while(result){ 
     ResultSet rs = proc.getResultSet() 
     println(rs) 
     result = proc.getMoreResults() 
 }
```

I see rc as object: `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet@1937bc8`

Comment: does it print `rs`?  Which line does it say the error is on?

Comment: @tim_yates No, this code doesn't print rs. Exception is generated on calling `proc.getInt(1)`
I see rc while I launched code:

    Connection connection = dbGetter().connection
            CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call Procedure_Name($param_1, $param_2)}")
            boolean result = proc.execute()
            while(result){
                ResultSet rs = proc.getResultSet()
                println(rs)
                result = proc.getMoreResults()
            }

Comment: @tim_yates Please, see update above. Also, I can share some others of my attempts.

Comment: So if you call `proc.getInt(1)` *after* the `while` loop, does it work?

Comment: @tim_yates oh, I missed this attempt. I will try and return with results.

Comment: @tim_yates Great Thanks! Now I get values. So, I will continue to exctract info from result set.